# Error in render only when accessing second instance of json file, vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm trying to access a JSON by callApi.
My .json file has 2 instances.

The code is working when I am accessing the first instance of the .json file.
But when I'm trying to access the second instance of the json there is a Error in render error:

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value1' of undefined"

.json structure:

```
{
  "d": {
    "value1": "300",
    "value2": "0000000002"
  }
}
```

helloworld.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
{{data.d.value1}} // when I'm removing ".value1" it works fine
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
    import jsonData from '../../static/json/test.json'
    export default {
      name: 'dash',
      data() {
        return {
          data: []
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.fetchData()
      },
      methods: {
        fetchData() {
          this.callApi()

            .then((responseData) => {
              this.data = responseData;

            })
        },

        callApi() {
          return Promise.resolve(jsonData)
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON File is not valid. Unlike JavaScript objects in JSON you can't have trailing commas. Maybe that is the issue?

If that doesn't fix it check on Vue devtools if you the data on the component looks like you would expect.

Comment: hey there, the json file is valid. the comma was my mistake, it isnt existing in my file.

Comment: and yes, with vue devtools everything looks correct.